# React native react-native-fitness

Tags: android, react-native, fitness

For some reason `Fitness.requestPermissions(permissions).then((authorized) => { console.log(authorized) }` always returns `false`. Also in documentation it says it `permissions` should be:

```
const permissions = [
    { kind: Fitness.PermissionKind.Step, access: Fitness.PermissionAccess.Read },
];
```

But the output of `console.log(Fitness.PermissionKind, Fitness.PermissionAccess)` is:

```
{"Activity": 2, "Calories": 3, "Distance": 1, "HeartRate": 4, "Step": 0} {"READ": 0, "WRITE": 1}
```

The `Fitness.PermissionAccess.Read` has appercase keys `{"READ": 0, "WRITE": 1}`

Any idea why `Fitness.requestPermissions([{kind:0, access: 0}])` (Fitness.PermissionKind.Step and Fitness.PermissionAccess.READ) always fails? It does show a pop up where I can select an ccount, but then permission is still not granted.

Answer (score 0):

You must have created the Client ID with the wrong debug.keystore, not the one provided with the React Native android project. You can get correct SHA-1 key using this command in android/app folder of react-native project:

```
keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

If this asks for the password, you can get the password from build.gradle file.